# Can Gaussian elimination fail finding null space?

Tags: gaussian-elimination

Is it possible to have $m$ rows with $n$ variables over F2, where $m < n$
that will have some combination of rows that can form a zero vector, but there will be no zero vectors in reduced-row echelon form?

Please provide an example of such a setup if this is indeed possible.

Comment: When you say "over the base two" do you mean "over the field with two elements"?

Comment: @saulspatz yeah, that what I meant, tnx, updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having $m$ rows and $n$ columns is obviously possible for matrices over $\Bbb F_2$, no matter the $m$ and $n$.

Gaussian elimination is an algorithm that works for matrices over any field and it is generally formulated in a way that may be applied verbatim in that generality (even when it is presented only for the case $A\in\Bbb R^{m\times n}$). I don't quite understand your objection, but I presume it revolves around a confusion between the action of $\Bbb Z$ over $V$, according to which you may write $x+x+x+x=4x$, and the action of $\Bbb F_2$, which is the one of interest and which only has $\overline 0\cdot x$ and $\overline 1\cdot x$.

Comment: I am using the Gaussian elimination to solve the matrix in the last step of the Quadratic Sieve algorithm. My goal is to find a combination of rows that when XORed together will result in a Zero vector. The question is: Assuming such a combination is possible, is it **promised** to find it when computing the reduced-row echelon form, given that $m < n$?

Comment: If I understand correctly, then no: at best you can find a *basis* of the space of relations, just like you do with $\Bbb R$.

Comment: No, I am saying that it is given that there is at least one combination of $m$ rows that will create a null space vector. The question is, is it promised that Gaussian elimination  will find it?

Comment: @IlyaGazman I don't understand, and I won't inspect any further because we are repeating ourselves. The Gaussian elimination agorithm does the same thing for matrices over $\Bbb F_2$ that it does for matrices over $\Bbb R$. If if it does for $\Bbb R$, it does for $\Bbb F_2$. If it doesn't for $\Bbb R$, then probably it doesn't for $\Bbb F_2$.

Comment: If the matrix is of less than full rank, Gaussian elimination will produce a row of all zeroes, just like it would over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Gae.S. sorry for confusing you with $\Bbb F_2$ it is truly irrelevant to what I am asking. I try making another question about it